# webform data binding- list inside another list

Tags: c#, winforms

I have spend some hours serching on this. I have following class

```
public class Tasks
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int,string> SubTasks { get; set; }    
}
```

My question is when I have `List<Tasks>` how to bind this to web form. I will be able to bind  Id and Name. But was unable to bind SubTasks  list

**Web form**

```
    <table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sub</th>
            </tr>
            <asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server">     
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ol>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ol>
                </LayoutTemplate>       
                <ItemTemplate>                
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("Id")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Name")%></td>
                        <%--<td>????</td>--%>
                    </tr>                
                </ItemTemplate>           
            </asp:ListView>
       </table>
```

I need this kind of output

```
------------------------------
id     |Name    |sub        |
-----------------------------
    1  |    abc | 1a  aaa   |
       |        | 1f  sss   |
       |        | 1v  ggg   |
-----------------------------
    2  |    ewq | 2a  ccc   |     
-----------------------------
    3  |    rty | 3a   bbb  |     
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Where you need the `SubTasks` to be bind? Same as `List<Tasks>`??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty-yes. I need display this as single information block. need to display the Id, Name with its subtasks

Comment: Are you clear what to do now?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty-nope. Still struggling with it

Comment: Show the code how you setting the data source to the grid?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty-        `Listview1.DataSource = TaskList;`
        `Page.DataBind();`

Comment: So in this case, SubTasks will have the parent Id or it own id? I can see only 3 columns in your grid `ID,Name,Sub`. What kind of output you expect here?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty- I have updated my question with the output I needed

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat different approach, but works

In your .aspx  add a  Literal control

i.e.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>       
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>       
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and in you .cs file

```
private void Fill()
        {
            var list = new List<Tasks>();

            // this is just to populate some sample data
            for(var i=1;i<5;i++)
            {
                var obj = new Tasks();
                obj.Id = "Id"+i.ToString();
                obj.Name = "Name " + i.ToString();
                var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                for(var j=1;j<3;j++)
                {
                    d.Add(j,"sub"+j.ToString());
                }
                obj.SubTasks=d;
                list.Add(obj);
            }

            Literal1.Text = "<table class='table1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Sub</th></tr>";

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var str = "<tr>";
                str +="<td>"+ item.Id.ToString()+"</td>";
                str += "<td>" + item.Name+ "</td>";
                if(item.SubTasks!=null)
                {
                     str += "<td><table>";
                    foreach(var sub in item.SubTasks)
                    {                       
                        str +="<tr>";
                        str += "<td>" + sub.Key.ToString() + "</td>";
                        str += "<td>" + sub.Value.ToString() + "</td>";
                        str += "</tr>";  
                    }
                     str += "</td></table>";
                }
                str += "</tr>";
                Literal1.Text += str;

            }

            Literal1.Text +="</table>";

        }
```

Now you just need to apply certain styles to table to get the display correct

Hope this helps!!